# Where to get soccer data per period?

Tags: football

I have searched for period data in soccer - like number of goals in 15,30,45,60,75,90 mins (15 minutes interval) - but I can't find any. Do you know any site giving this data?

Comment: Welcome to [sports.se]! This question might be better suited for our sister site [opendata.se].

Comment: Are you looking for data that you can use for an analysis? Are you interested in a particular league or competition? There are plenty of websites (WhoScored, Transfermarkt, FutMob, etc.) that provide data that you could web scrape, either programmatically or manually, to get the times goals are scored and then do some aggregation on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can check soccerstats.com it has plenty of information about football leagues, teams and like what you asked for goals in time periods as well. For example for the Premier League here is a link:[premier league timing stats](https://www.soccerstats.com/timing.asp?league=england)